# Fill window height with floated elements and scale horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I want to achieve opposite of the normal behaviour with floated elements.

Instead of filling the viewport width it should will the height. And instead of enlarging the height - it should enlarge the width to the right. On top I don't know how many items there will be…

Here is an example width a fixed container width, which does the job, but only if I know how much items there are and with Media Queries for viewport heights.

```
<stlye>
#horizontal-container {
 background: rgb(123,123,123);
 width: 1500px;
 height: 100vh;
}

ul.item-list {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul.item-list li.item {
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<div id="horizontal-container">
 <ul class="item-list clearfix">
      <li class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
      </li>
      <li class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      </li>
      <li class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x150">
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bananenbiegerei/e1dnagpv/16/

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is what you want: https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/ I don't know if you can use it. It uses `display: flex`.

Comment: Thanks, Halcyon. It is close. The problem are the columns. If there are images inside the list they don't float but stick to there columns.

Comment: Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojNEaR. 
And here a dummy, how it should look like: http://hk-static.bananenbiegerei.de/
The problem with that example: a fixed container width, around the list of element. Therefore I need to know how much elements there are…
Any suggestion?